# Phantom Wallet question

Tags: phantom-wallet

I followed the guide here https://docs.phantom.app/solana/integrating-phantom/extension-and-in-app-browser-web-apps/establishing-a-connection and was able to connect on "localhost" but when I tried a domain over HTTP it doesn't prompt to connect. Does it only prompt to connect via HTTPS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct. For security purposes, Phantom only injects its provider into websites that begin with `https://`, or if the host is `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. Encrypting your web traffic and upgrading to `https://` will restore functionality.

See: https://docs.phantom.app/solana/resources/faq#why-cant-i-access-phantom-on-my-website